# C++ Printing out individual characters of a text file to screen

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a text file called "maze.txt" that looks like this:

```
###############
Sacbifnsdfweovw
###############
```

I want to check whether the letter on the left one down from the top is 'S', and then to check whether the one to the right of that is an alphabetical character. Then, I'll keep checking whether the characters that follow the previous letter are alphabetical characters.
These letters are to be stored in my vector 'path'.
Finally, I'll print to screen each of the alphabetical letters we've been through. But for some reason, for that chunk of letters above, the screen only prints out 'S' and 'a', and none of the others. What's wrong? Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("maze.txt");
    if (file) {
        vector<char> vec(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (istreambuf_iterator<char>())); // Imports characters from file
        vector<char> path;                      // Declares path as the vector storing the characters from the file
        int x = 17;                             // Declaring x as 17 so I can use it with recursion below
        char entrance = vec.at(16);             // 'S', the entrance to the maze
        char firstsquare = vec.at(x);           // For the first walkable square next to the entrance

        // Check that the entrance really has 'S'
        if (entrance == 'S')                    
        { 
            path.push_back(entrance);           // Store 'S' into vector 'path'
        }

        // Check if the first path is an alphabetical character and thus walkable
        if (isalpha(firstsquare))               
        {
            path.push_back(firstsquare);        // Store that character into vector 'path'
            isalpha(vec.at(x++));               // Recurse 'isalpha' to the next adajcent square of the maze;
        }                                       // checking next character

        cout << "Path is: ";                    // Printing to screen the first part of our statement

        // This loop to print to the screen all the contents of the vector 'path'.
        for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = path.begin(); i != path.end(); ++i)  // 
        {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
        system ("pause");                       // Keeps the black box that pops up, open, so we can see results.
        return 0;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance! I am new to C++ by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this looks like a learning project (homework, self-learning, whatever), I'm only going to give hints.

I think this line (especially the comments) indicates the problem:

```
isalpha(vec.at(x++)); // Recurse 'isalpha' to the next adajcent square of the maze;
```

You aren't "recursing" anything and you are ignoring the result of isalpha. You are only determining if the next character is alphabetical and then doing nothing with it, and only that one character.

Comment: Ah I fixed it somehow now using a for-loop instead: for (y=0; isalpha(vec.at(x)); x++)
  {
   path.push_back(vec.at(x));
  } Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Your code might be more clear with a while loop. while(isalphs(vec.at(x)) { x++; }.